# Disable entry versioning

Tags: config, configuration, entry-versions

Had a quick search online and I can't find a way to disable entry versioning.

Is this possible? There's some plugins that do this but I'm hoping there's some config I can set somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

No need for a plugin, just don't check this option

Comment: Is there a way to set this programmatically?

Comment: Of course grab the section model and set the property to false
`$section->enableVersioning = false; Craft::$app->getSections()->saveSection($section);`

Comment: Ok, maybe that was a bad response to your answer but as I said in my original question I am looking to set this through configuration rather than using a migration or something similar. Is there a way to do it through configuration?

Comment: No. Why can't you just not tick the checkbox? What's the purpose of a checkbox if you want to ignore it, the checkbox is actually your configuration

Comment: I can "just tick the checkbox" but I want to globally enforce this behaviour on every project so it cannot be overriden - even if an admin wanted to change it. https://12factor.net/config

Comment: You can create a module and set up an event to set it to false during `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_SECTION`